# MEVN Stack. Linking to Uploaded Images

Tags: node.js, image, express, vue.js, file-upload

Hi I implemented an image upload system on my website but now I don't know how to link to that image.

My root directory has a client folder, for my vuejs app, and a server folder, for the back end logic.

When users upload a file, the file goes to a public folder under the server folder.  This is where I got stuck.

How do I then link to that uploaded image from my vuejs app that is in the client folder.

Keep in mind that my express app is running on port 5000 while my vuejs app is running on port 8080.

In my img tags I tried linking to the image by using "http://localhost:5000/public/image/imagename" and "http://localhost:5000/image/imagename" but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your express.js logic you should expose your public folder

```
app.use('/public', express.static(`${__dirname}/public/`));
```

I'm supposing your express entry point is in the same backend folder as '/public/ folder.

And then you can just access it like you've tried before on: `http://localhost:5000/public/image/imagename`